# Vim: How to auto-complete words in insert mode past word boundaries (e.g. punctation)?

Tags: vim

I am used to auto-complete words in insert mode using `C-P` or `C-N`.

Say, I do some object-oriented programming and write `myObject.foo()` a lot. Then after writing `my`, Vim's auto-completion feature (`C-P`/`C-N`) will only complete `myObject` and not `myObject.foo()`.

Does Vim have any commands for auto-completing words, also considering punctation e.g. (`.`) as part of the word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you’ve accepted an autocompletion, triggering the same one again will “continue” it. That is, if the buffer already has

```
myObject.foo
```

And you use `<C-n>` to get

```
myObject
```

Then pressing `<C-x><C-n>` again will finish with

```
myObject.foo
```

Alternately, you can probably fiddle with `iskeyword`, but this has far-reaching side-effects.

Comment: Thanks. What’s the purpose of `<C-x>`? I’ve never seen or used it before for auto-completion. Normally, I accept an auto-completion using `<C-y>`. In the above, you don’t accept an auto-completion? Pressing `<C-n>` merely goes forward  to the next suggestion for completion.

Comment: I do, for the first one. `<C-x>` is the autocompletion “prefix”—check `:help ins-completion`

Comment: Thanks. Read it now. Do you know why pressing `<C-x><C-n>` in my case results in `.foo` and not just `.`? Also, the documentation says that it looks for a "keyword" of alphabetic characters, but "." is not an alphabetic character?

Comment: @Shuzheng i do not, but it’s probably intended (i wrote from memory and could well be wrong). It looks for a series of keyword characters, really, using iskeyword (which I mentioned). So it has to skip past the dot to find one is my guess

Comment: Thanks. How can I list the current keyword characters? If I try to `:echo` different variables, it says that they are defined.

Comment: You want to check `set iskeyword` and the relevant help.